# modifying admin groups M2M field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change the list of groups that are being saved for a given user in Django. I override the UserAdmin class to do so, and my save_form() method gets triggered properly.  From there I'm trying to overwrite the values in form.cleaned_data['groups'] or using form.data.setlist('groups', ...). However, none of the modifications that I make get saved into the database. Instead, the items that were set by the request user are saved, my code has no impact (although it is run.)

My question is: Am I modifying the right values in the form? Why do these dictionaries have no impact on the result saved to the database? There is a form.instance variable which holds the user being modified. I'm wondering if I could use this to reset the groups after running form.save(commit=False), but I'd like to see if there's a clean way to override M2M fields from save_form..

Here is another attempt I just made, since I've noticed the return of form_save() is the User instance being modified:

```
def save_form(self, request, form, change):
    f_save = form.save(commit=False)
    f_save.groups = new_queryset # here i'm just overriding the queryset for the groups.
    f_save.save()
    return f_save
```

Just like the other attempts with form.cleaned_data and form.data. This has no impact on the final groups saved into the database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance needs to be committed before many to many fields can be used. According to the docs:

```
You can’t associate it with a Publication until it’s been saved:
```

You then don't need to call .save on the instance because it does not change that record at all. It just add records to the through table.

Could you see if this works?

```
def save_form(self, request, form, change):
    f_save = form.save()
    f_save.groups = new_queryset
    return f_save
```

Comment: Nope. It does not work. The original queryset gets saved in the end.

Comment: Actually, it does not work when doing f_save = form.save(commit=False)

But if I change to f_save = form.save(), then I get another error:
'UserForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Comment: Hmm thats strange. Did you override the form in any way?